# Define rules for icu transform in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, icu, transliteration

I couldn't find any working example of using 'rules' in 'icu_transform' filter.
The only example that I found is following:

```
"my_icu_transformer_rules": {
   "type": "icu_transform",
   "id": "test",
   "dir": "forward",
   "rules": "a > b; b > c;"
}
```

But I got **Illegal ID test**. If I remove id it executes but does nothing to given text.

What's the way to apply rules in isu transform filter?

P.S. Just in case, the overall task is to translit from Latin to Cyrillic. The default icu transliteration (set 'id' to "Any-Cyrillic") doesn't work the way I need. For example, it transforms 'ch' to 'цх', but I need to map it to 'ч'.